# How can I add parameters to a dockerio.running state in Salt?

Tags: docker, salt-stack

I'm trying to run a 3rd party docker image from salt.
From the command line, the required statement is something like:

```
docker run -d progrium/consul -server -bootstrap
```

From Salt however I don't know how to pass the parameters (-server and -bootstrap)
Is there a way to do that?

regards, Frank

Answer (score 1):

You can peek at the Dockerfile, and use the entrypoint to pass to dockerng yourself.

```
docker_consul:
  dockerng.running:
    - name: consul
    - image: progrium/consul
    - port_bindings: "8500:8500"
    - restart_policy: always
    - entrypoint: "/bin/start -server -bootstrap"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
salt 'dockerhost' docker.run 'progrium/consul -server -bootstrap'
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, jordanhill123